# How to handle date input in Laravel

Tags: forms, date, laravel, localization, formatting

I'm working on an app that allows the user to edit several dates in a form. The dates are rendered in the European format (DD-MM-YYYY) while the databases uses the default YYYY-MM-DD format.

There are several ways to encode/decode this data back and forth from the database to the user, but they all require a lot of code:

- Use a helper function to convert the date before saving and after retrieving (very cumbersome, requires much code)
- Create a separate attribute for each date attribute, and use the `setNameAttribute` and `getNameAttribute` methods to decode/encode (also cumbersome and ugly, requires extra translations/rules for each attribute)
- Use JavaScript to convert the dates when loading and submitting the form (not very reliable)

So what's the most efficient way to store, retrieve and validate dates and times from the user?

Comment: Did you look if you could achieve what you want using Carbon which is built into laravel ?

Comment: Parsing dates itself is not the problem, I already use Carbon for that. The problem is where to put the code to convert the dates, I don't want to add tons of repeating conversion code in my controllers/views. Also Carbon throws an exception when you try to parse a date that has the wrong format, this is not ideal when dealing with user input.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At some point, you have to convert the date from the view format to the database format. As you mentioned, there are a number of places to do this, basically choosing between the back-end or the front-end.

I do the conversion at the client side (front-end) using javascript (you can use http://momentjs.com to help with this). The reason is that you may need different formats depending on the locale the client is using (set in the browser or in his profile preferences for example). Doing the format conversion in the front-end allows you to convert to these different date formats easily.

Another advantage is that you can then use the `protected $dates` property in your model to have Laravel handle (get and set) these dates automatically as a Carbon object, without the need for you to do this (see https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L126).

As for validation, you need can then use Laravel's built-in validation rules for dates, like this:

```
'date' => 'required|date|date_format:Y-n-j'
```

Comment: "You should use either date or date_format when validating a field, not both." – [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-date-format)

Answer (score 3):

While client-side is good for UX, it doesn't let you be sure, all will be good.

At some point you will need server-side validation/convertion anyway.

But here's the thing, it's as easy as this:

```
// after making sure it's valid date in your format
// $dateInput = '21-02-2014'

$dateLocale = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $dateInput);

// or providing users timezone
$dateLocale = 
   DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $dateInput, new DateTime('Europe/London'));

$dateToSave = $dateLocale
           // ->setTimeZone(new TimeZone('UTC'))   if necessary
           ->format('Y-m-d');
```

et voila!

---

**Obviously, you can use brilliant [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) to make it even easier:**

```
$dateToSave = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $dateInput, 'Europe/London')
        ->tz('UTC')
        ->toDateString(); // '2014-02-21'
```

---

**Validation**

You say that Carbon throws exception if provided with wrong input. Of course, but here's what you need to validate the date:

```
'regex:/\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}/|date_format:d-m-Y'

// accepts 1-2-2014, 01-02-2014
// doesn't accept 01-02-14
```

This regex part is necessary, if you wish to make sure year part is 4digit, since PHP would consider date `01-02-14` valid, despite using `Y` format character (making year = `0014`).

Answer (score 1):

The best way I found is overriding the `fromDateTime` from `Eloquent`.

```
class ExtendedEloquent extends Eloquent {
    public function fromDateTime($value)
    {
        // If the value is in simple day, month, year format, we will format it using that setup.
        // To keep using Eloquent's original fromDateTime method, we'll convert the date to timestamp,
        // because Eloquent already handle timestamp.
        if (preg_match('/^(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})$/', $value)) {
            $value = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $value)
                ->startOfDay()
                ->getTimestamp();
        }

        return parent::fromDateTime($value);
    }
}
```

I'm new in PHP, so I don't know if it's the best approach.
Hope it helps.

Edit:

Of course, remember to set all your dates properties in `dates` inside your model. eg:

```
protected $dates = array('IssueDate', 'SomeDate');
```