# How to validate AM/PM on Laravel5?

Tags: php, regex, validation, laravel-5

I'm looking for validate 12 hours.
A.M. 00:00 ~ 11:59 and P.M. 12:00 ~ 23:59.

Input value come like this.

```
<input type="text" name="am" value="00:00" />
<input type="text" name="am" value="11:59" />

<input type="text" name="pm" value="12:00" />
<input type="text" name="pm" value="23:59" />
```

So I made validate like this.

```
'am' => ['regex:/^(1[01]|0[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]$/'],
'pm' => ['regex:/^(2[0-3]|1[2-9]):[0-5][0-9]$/'],
```

Does Laravel have any good validation without regex? (like after:tomorrow)
I don't wanna use regex that make code difficult to reading comprehension.
Any Ideas?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24965799/how-to-handle-date-input-in-laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `date_format` validation in Laravel out of the box.

You can read about it here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-date-format.

You may also make you your own validation by extending Laravel validation, then you can reuse it later. you can read about it here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: I'm already use date_format: H:i . I know date_format: H:i A validate 10:00 AM or 10:00 PM. But what I want is validate 24hours am/pm. Not 12hours am/pm. I don't wanna use the string 'am/pm'. It seems nothing to way that come true. So I write regex. Would you tell me example?

Comment: I don't know if I got you or not, but I don't think so, maybe you should use the same regex, and that's why Laravel has considered regex!

Comment: Hmm guess so use regex is best way. Thanks!